# Why content of the MultipartHttpServletRequest is empty?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload 2 documents using AngularJs. The user fills the information like Name, Date of Birth, Gender etc. If these data successfully stored in the database through spring controller, 2 documents should be stored.

**JS**

Below code is for adding and removing the documents.

```
$scope.items = [];
$scope.item = {};

$scope.addItem = function (item)
    {   
          if ($scope.item.file != undefined){
              $scope.items.push( $scope.item);
              $scope.item = {};
          }
          else {
              alert("Please open a file before adding");
             }
     }
$scope.removeItem = function (item)
    {
         for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++)
            {
                 if ($scope.items[i] === item)
                    {
                            $scope.items.splice(i, 1);
                            break;
                            }
            }
    }
```

Below code is for submitting the form data and documents.

```
$scope.submit = function()
     { 
         var formData =
                {
                    fullName     : $scope.fullName,
                    fatherName   : $scope.fatherName,
                    gender       : $scope.gender,
                    contactNumber: $scope.contactNumber,
                    dateofbirth  : $scope.dateofbirth,
                    subDate      : new Date()
                };

        $http.post('userdetails', formData ).success(function(response)
            {
                if ($scope.items.length > 0)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0 ; i < $scope.items.length ; i++)
                          {
                                $scope.uploadItem(response.id, $scope.items[i]);
                          }
                    }  

            }).error(function(error)
                            {
                                alert(error);
                            });

    };

$scope.uploadItem = function(id, file)
{
       var data = new FormData();
       data.append('id', id);
       data.append('file', file);

       $http.post('multipleSave', data, {
             headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined,
                        enctype:'multipart/form-data' }

                     }).success(function(data) {
                        $log.debug("Upload Successfull");

                    }).error(function(error) {
                         $log.debug("Upload failure");
                     });
 };
```

First form data would be stored and if it is success, Documents should be passed. Here id is auto generated which is returned in response from the database after storing the form data. All these happen in one click from front end.

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/multipleSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public @ResponseBody void uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        Iterator<String> fileName=request.getFileNames();
        MultipartFile file= request.getFile(fileName.hasNext());
        System.out.println("file");
}
```

**In Spring Configuration**

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
</bean>
```

I ran in debugging mode and I saw that content of MultipartHttpServletRequest is empty. It is not receiving any file.
Any help on this?

Comment: please post your configs as well.

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You have all the configs in place. Just update the controller to below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/multipleSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException {

  for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        MultipartFile file = files[i];
        // do something
  }
}
```

The uploaded file(s) should be fetched from array of `MultipartFile` and not from the `MultipartHttpServletRequest`.

Let know in comments if you need any further information / help.

*Ref* - see [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/).

Comment: I ran in debug mode but file=MultipartFile[0] is still empty. It is not entering the for loop also :( Please help me

Comment: Ok.. Try writing a simple JUnit with mock multipart request to test the controller. This way we would be able to narrow down if issue is at client or server side.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your problem is in ajax headers - my headers from working implementation looks like:

```
headers: {'Content-Type': undefined, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'utf-8' }
```

You should not use content-type and enctype together.

Also, when I used file.getOriginalFilename() method in spring-mvc it was not working because form name encoding is *iso-8859-1*. I think, `request.getFileNames()` also will not work. I used the following approach:

```
MultipartFile file = request.getFile("file");
String fileName = new String(file.getOriginalFilename().getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
```

Also, I see you are appending additional params to file via `formdata.append`. 
It's OK, but don't forget to use separate method for getting params: file extracted from `MultipartHttpServletRequest` via `request.getFile/getFiles` while additional params extracted with somethiing like that:  `String id=  request.getParameter("id");`

Comment: It is giving "Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Transfer-Encoding"  error if I use 'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'utf-8'. Also 'MultipartHttpServletRequest' is empty when I checked in debug mode. Please help me

Comment: @Yogesh, are you performing CORS requests? I mean, for example, www.app1.com loads page with javascript which uploads file to www.app2.com? If yes, you should add to upload controller `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Comment: I'm not uploading any file as soon as page is loaded. I'm manually uploading the file using input type as file

Comment: OK, is page with input-file hosted on same origin with spring controller web site? If you testing, is input=file on localhost:8080/app1 and site with controller is in localhost:8081/app2/controllerMapping? Or both of them in some  localhost:port/siteName?

Comment: input=file is in http://localhost:8080/app1. I'm posting some form data like, name and gender through $httlp and if it is successful, files should be posted. All these things happens on one click from HTML. You can refer the code.